# ¿Cómo obtener los meses de diferencia entre 2 fechas en Java?

Tags: java, date

Si tengo 2 variables tipo Date:

```
Date fecha1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/05/2017");
Date fecha2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/08/2018");
```

que el resultado me devuela 15 meses de direfencia.

Existe alguna manera de obtenerlo?

Comment: La lógica tiene errores, ya que no considera la diferencia con respecto a los días. Saludos,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Fecha {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Calendar inicio = new GregorianCalendar();
            Calendar fin = new GregorianCalendar();
            inicio.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/05/2017"));
            fin.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("01/08/2018"));
            int difA = fin.get(Calendar.YEAR) - inicio.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int difM = difA * 12 + fin.get(Calendar.MONTH) - inicio.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            System.out.println(difM);
        } catch(ParseException ex) {

        }
    }
}
```

Puedes utilizar [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

Primero lo que hacemos es establecer 2 fechas, una de inicio y otra final.
`inicio` y `fin` en este caso.

Después calculamos la diferencia en años entre las dos fechas (`difA`). Esto en caso de que la diferencia entre meses sea mayor a 12 podamos calcularlo.

Una vez hecho esto necesitamos calcular la cantidad de meses entre esos años, para eso multiplicamos 12 por la diferencia de años entre las dos fechas y a esto le sumamos el número del mes de la fecha final y por último le restamos el número del mes de inicio y obtenemos la diferencia en meses entre las fechas (`difM`).

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, no se como no lo vi de esa manera, de multiplicar la diferencia de años por 12 meses y a este sumarle la diferencia de meses que se obtiene entre las 2 fechas. Saludos!!