# Iniciar fecha a hoy en lugar de a 1900

Tags: java, android, date

Al ingresar al calendario inicia en el año 1900, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que inicie con la fecha de hoy?

```
package com.example.lu;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import com.example.lu.nombramientos.R;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class Tec3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText Año1,Mes1,Dia1, Año2,Mes2,Dia2, resultado;
    private Button boton;
    int a1,m1,d1,a2,m2,d2, rA, rM, rD, Rt;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tec3);

        Año1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dtAñoInicio);
        Mes1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dtMesInicio);
        Dia1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dtDiaInicio);
        Año2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dtAñoFin);
        Mes2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dtMesFin);
        Dia2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dtDiaFin);
        boton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnTotalDias);
        resultado = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nTotal);

        Calendar C2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        a1 = C2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m1 = C2.get(Calendar.MONTH) +1;
        d1 = C2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        a2 = C2.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        m2 = C2.get(Calendar.MONTH) +1;
        d2 = C2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        Dia1.setText(""+d1);
        Mes1.setText(""+m1);
        Año1.setText(""+a1);
        Dia2.setText(""+d1);
        Mes2.setText(""+m1);
        Año2.setText(""+a1);


        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                a1 = Integer.valueOf(Año1.getText().toString());
                a2 = Integer.valueOf(Año2.getText().toString());
                m1 = Integer.valueOf(Mes1.getText().toString());
                m2 = Integer.valueOf(Mes2.getText().toString());
                d1 = Integer.valueOf(Dia1.getText().toString());
                d2 = Integer.valueOf(Dia2.getText().toString());

                rA = a2 - a1;
                rM = m2 - m1;
                rD = d2 - d1;

                Rt = (rA*360)+(rM*30)+(rD+1);

                resultado.setText(""+Rt);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola nestor, y tu avance, es decir lo que has intentado hasta ahora, podrías añadirlo por favor, así sera mas fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu interés, ya lo inclui en la pregunta

Comment: Se supone que el usuario selecciona las dos fechas (año-mes-dia) no seria mas fácil usar un CalendarView ? para que seleccione las fechas fácilmente sin tener que usar Edittext's

Comment: Disculpa Ashley, es que soy totalmente nuevo en esto y es un proyecto de investigación que debo presentar el Lunes. Viendo videos me encontré con algo como esto y lo modifiqué a mi conveniencia, pero tengo ese problema. Talvez me puedas asesorar un poco más si eres tan amable.

Comment: Claro, si de apoco se aprende, intentare ayudarte lo mas que pueda. con calerdarView es mas facil para el usuario manejar fechas(año-mes-dia) ademas esta misma clase te ofrece varias funciones para utilizar.

Comment: Hola Ashley... Al ingresar al calendario inicia en el año 1900, cómo puedo hacer para que inicie con la fecha de hoy?

Comment: Añade tu codigo en la pregunta ...

Comment: Esta respuesta ya ha sido respondida, [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/106342/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-los-meses-de-diferencia-entre-2-fechas-en-java) tiene la respuesta. Espero que le sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes obtener la fecha actual y luego setter el valor a la varible donde muestras tu componente.
Puedes hacerlo de diferentes maneras

```
import java.util.Calendar
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

para obtener el día mes y año puedes seguir la documentación oficial de de Calendar [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)